# Changing visible view controller in containerView swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, uicontainerview

How can I change the visible view controller in a containerView (i.e. the one which is referenced by the embed segue) using the page curl animation to transition between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

**UIPageViewController**

Embed a UIPageViewController (see the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/)) in the containerView.  Initialise the page view controller with the `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.PageCurl`, and use `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` to set the first VC to be the view controller that is currently embedded in the containerView.  Then use the same method to switch to the new VC you want to display.

This option has the advantage of providing gesture-based transitions out of the box, but UIPageViewController can be confusing so there's a bit of a learning curve.

**UIView transition**

A simpler solution is just to use the `UIView` method `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`.  (see the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:)).  There is an option to use the page curl transition. There is a slight complication in that your two views are managed by other view controllers, so you need also to use the view controller methods `addChildViewController:`, `didMoveToParentViewController`, `willMoveToParentViewController` and `removeFromParentViewController`.  This is described in the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) (under "Implementing a Custom Container View Controller").